# Change editor font size in kile

Tags: kile

I am using Kile 2.1.3 on Ubuntu 13.10. How can I change the editor font size?

I went to "Configure Kile" > "Fonts & Colors" > "Font" > "Size" and changed it to 12. But that did not have any effect. What am I doing wrong?

NB: This question is not about font sizes in the LaTeX output. It's just about the font size displayed in the editor.

Comment: could you test if pressing "ctrl" + "+" while on the main window enlarge the font size?

Comment: Hm, worked fine here (Kile 2.1.3 in Kubuntu 13.10). Does restarting Kile help? What about holding down Ctrl and scrolling with the cursor in the text, does that work?

Comment: "ctrl" + "+" worked and closing and opening it again worked also. Was confused because on Win it changes immediately after changing the settings. Maybe turn comments into answers so that I can accept them.

Answer (score 3):

Possible solutions:

- restarting Kile after changing setting
- Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> to enlarge the font (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> decreases the editor font size)

Comment: In my case the settings are not saved,  Ctrl+ works but I have to do it each time

Answer (score 1):

For me the following works:

1. Install Kate (a text editor).
2. Chane font size in Kate.
3. Kile will use the same font size after that.

Please explain what happened. (I am interested.)

Comment: After installing Kate, changing fonts in Kile also works. I started having this issue when I changed from the TeXLive installation provided by my Linux distribution (OpenSUSE) to the vanilla one from TUG.